# Site is deployed on Azure, but I cannot get access index.html

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I am trying to build and release front-end app based on quasar on Azure Portal.

Building is OK.

Releasing is OK, but when I go to the apps link I see standard welcome screen:

[image]

I checked deployed code via SSH it is there, but it is located on "/home/site/wwwroot/index.html"

[image]

How do I point to the correct folder with my app? Thank you!

Comment: Any update on this issuw?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there is an official doc about this: [how to set the default document in a Node.js app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/things-you-should-know-web-apps-and-linux#set-your-default-document-in-a-nodejs-app-using-javascriptapplies-to-azure-app-service-on-linuxapplies-to-web-app-for-containers).

It uses express to solve it,  Create index.js there with the following code, then restart your app then it will work.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
var options = {
index: 'index.html'
};
server.use('/', express.static('/home/site/wwwroot', options));
server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Except this, there is another way to solve it, use pm2 since that is already part of the stack. Add the below startup command for the app:

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon
```

[image]

After restart the app, it will pick the index pages from the wwwroot.